# Displaying different breadcrumb for that same controller and action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I used tutorial from http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/08/10/mvcsitemapprovider-4-seo-features#canonical-tag for making different breadcrumb path for the same controller and action, like:

```
Home > About
Home > Another About
```

Everything works fine in solution attached to tutorial but when i'm making new solution (mvc4/mvc5) it doesn't work. I have compared my files with files from tutorial and they are the same (one change is that i'm using MvcSiteMapProvider version 4.6.1 and in tutorial there is a version 4.0.1). I'm using Visual Studio 2013, .net 4.5, my routing is default, i`m adding to second about link 1234 variable. I simpilified my sitemap to:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="About" controller="Home" action="About" key="About" />
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Another About" controller="Home" action="About" something="1234" />
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

Another About actionlink link in Home index is /Home/About?something=1234 (second About is without ?something=1234) but when i`m clicking on it my breadcrumb looks:

```
 Home > About    instead Home > Another About
```

Could someone can help me?
Radomir

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in [the documentation](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Routing-Basics), the default behavior expects you to add a node for each custom parameter combination. That is, by default there is a 1 to many relationship between route/action parameters and SiteMap nodes.

If these custom parameters correspond to database keys, it is typically best to add the nodes using a [IDynamicNodeProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-IDynamicNodeProvider) implementation.

If the "something" parameter is not related to the content on the page, you can override the behavior by setting `preservedRouteParameters="something"`. The effect is that whatever the value of "something" is, it will be copied over from the current request into the node and then it will always match. This makes a 1 to 1 relationship between the route/action parameter and the node.

For an in depth look at the matching options and when to use them, read [How to Make MvcSiteMapProvider Remember a User's Position](http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position).